# AWS - Redirect website's subdirectory to another Elastic Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a web application **exmple.com** which I am migrating to AWS. I have deployed the web application to the Elastic Beanstalk and used Route53 to redirect the domain to the Beanstalk app.
I also have another PHP web service in the sub directory on this domain i.e. **exmple.com/phpwebservice/**. I have again deployed the PHP web service to the Elastic Beanstalk which works fine using the Beanstalk URL but I want to redirect **exmple.com/phpwebservice/** to the new Beanstalk URL so that the users who are already using this service won't have to change their request url.

I can obviously use Route53 to redirect the subdomain like phpservice.example.com to the Beanstalk PHP app but I want to redirect it from the Add-on domain i.e.  **exmple.com/phpwebservice/**.

I have checked similar questions on this platform but can't get them to work. Can someone please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: This won't be possible through a DNS service (Route53) as DNS is only responsible for resolving the domain name (`example.com`) to an IP address; it's not involved with what comes after (`/phpwebservice`). With that said, you could still define rules within the load balancer of the first Beanstalk application to forward traffic to the second.
For people to be able to help better, could you elaborate on your Beanstalk configurations? In particular, what kind of load balancer are you using; classic or application load balancer. Instructions will vary depending on the type.

Comment: I don't even need a load balancer. I am simply adding an A Record for the domain to point to the Elastic Beanstalk Environment. I can use load balancer though if required. I have tried the application load balancer and that works well as well, Can you guide me in the right direction to configure this?

Comment: Without a load balancer, you'd probably need to redirect the `/phpwebservice` traffic from within your application.
However, it's easy enough to add a load balancer within Beanstalk configurations; your `A` record would still be pointing to your Beanstalk environment.
I'll explain more in an answer.

Comment: On further investigation, it's not possible to route traffic from an application load balancer to Beanstalk; target groups can only be instances, IPs, or Lambda but not domains (as I was hoping).
This leaves with you with a number of options I can think of:
1- Within your application code on the first Beanstalk app, write a redirect to the second app.
2- If you'd rather not modify your code, create a separate proxy.
3-  Move your second app from Beanstalk to EC2. This way you'd be able to register EC2 instance(s) as targets within the load balancer of the first beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. I will look into redirecting from the code base. It is very easy to redirect from cPanel redirect rules but cannot do it within AWS