# How do I point my AWS Elastic Beanstalk flask application to a folder in my domain example.com/app instead of the base example.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have an Elastic Beanstalk app I created which is up and running. I have a domain in Route 53 which currently only has a landing page. I don't want to replace the landing page, instead, I want the app to be accessible at example.com/app. Notice the app route at the end. How do I accomplish this in Route 53?

What I have tried so far:

1. I managed to point it to the base domain level, that was easy. But that is not what I want, I still need the current site to be the main site and have the EBS app available on /app
2. I managed to get it working on app.example.com, which again is not what I want

I still cannot figure out how to do this. Any help would be dearly appreciated. I am fairly new to AWS and routing and stuff.

Comment: Very similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/63119092/495455

Answer (score 0):

You **can't do this from Route53**. R53 is DNS, and it does not have any notion of URL paths. Instead you can do this from CouldFront. Specifically, you would have to put a CF distro between your R53 and your EB. When you setup origin and its `behaviour` for your CF distro you can specify [Path Pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html?icmpid=docs_cf_help_panel#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) as `/app`.